# C# Getting values from xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to get both latitude(lat) and longitude(lon) values from xml file.

The XML file is generated throw Web-request using the below code.

**Code**

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("#") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("#", "#");
var response = request.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
String xmlString = result;
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlString));
reader.Read();
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(reader, System.Data.XmlReadMode.Auto);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
lbllat.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();//for example 
lbllong.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
```

But the code gives this following error msg.

> Error: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 2, position 483

Mainly The error occurred because XML tags do not accept spaces on.

Generated xml file format.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <code>0</code>
  <msg>OK</msg>
  <data>
    <agentid>1</agentid>
    <imei>3224</imei>
    <typeid>2</typeid>
    <type>Truck</type>
    <vehiclenumber>12121</vehiclenumber>
    <folder>folder1</folder>
    <created_time>1493813160</created_time>
    <current_mileage>4232</current_mileage>
    <status>
      <active>1</active>
      <speed>0</speed>
      <direction>303</direction>
      <lat>3.79092</lat>
      <lon>69.51279</lon>
      <alt>1</alt>
      <satsinview>18</satsinview>
      <unixtimestamp>1503389638</unixtimestamp>
      <sensors>
        <Ignition sensor="">Off</Ignition sensor><External power="" supply="">On</External power supply>
      </sensors>
    </status>
  </data>
</root>
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Yeah, `</Ignition sensor>` is wrong. Should just be `</Ignition>`. Same with your `</External>` tag. Don't include the attributes in the closing tag.

Comment: yes but i cannot change the format since its  generated throw Web-request.

Comment: The best you can do is to pre-process `xmlString`, i.e. replace "<Ignition sensor" with "<IgnitionSensor" and so on to make it valid XML, then parse it.

Comment: The web request is returning invalid xml. You might want to bring it to their attention - see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags for details.

In the meantime, as has been suggested, your best bet is pre-processing the xml (although I'd recommend stripping the attributes from the closing tags to give you valid xml, rather than combining the tag name and the attribute name as suggested above as that would cause issues with the attributes in the opening tag).

Answer (score 0):

First, get the XML fixed, but if you can't then use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) to retrieve the mal-formed XML. It's pretty good for webscraping, and dealing with badly formed XML.